# Show signature in all pages of PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Hello I am wanting to show the digital signature on all pages of the PDF, I researched but only found a method that inserts an image on all pages, but my certificate has no image, can someone help me. 
Below, a piece of code:

```
sap.SetVisibleSignature( new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle( 10f, 10f, 110f, 30f ), reader.NumberOfPages, null );
sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
sap.Acro6Layers = true;
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature( PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1 );
dic.Date = new PdfDate( sap.SignDate );
signName = iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields( sap.Certificate ).GetField( "CN" );
dic.Name = signName;

if ( sap.Reason != null ) dic.Reason = sap.Reason;
if ( sap.Location != null ) dic.Location = sap.Location;
```

his code only shows the signature on the last page of the PDF.

Comment: I'm currently at the ISO committee meeting in New York discussing ISO-32000-2, and (among other things) this requirement. Your requirement will be declared "invalid PDF" in the next version of the ISO specification for PDF. It's already mentioned in one of Adobe's technical notes, but we'll now make your requirement "invalid" in the ISO specification. So please don't expect an answer: implementing your requirement would lead to an invalid PDF.

Comment: You have an example of code that I can use to sign documents that do not give me future problems?Recalling that must show the signature on all pages.

Comment: See my answer: your question is invalid.

Comment: BTW, using `ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1` is a bad choice anyways. In ISO 32000-1 (i.e. since 2008) the use of **adbe.pkcs7.detached** is recommended, and I assume in ISO 32000-2 probably **ETSI.CAdES.detached** will be added as an alternative recommendation. I doubt, though, that **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** will ever rise again.

Comment: mkl and references ADOBE_PPKMS can I still use?
I changed to ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED, but now Adobe Reader says the PDF was changed after being signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken a screen shot from the draft of the upcoming specification.

[image]

You're asking to have one signature that is represented by multiple widget annotations (one on each page). However, the spec says:

> signature fields shall never refer to more than one annotation.

Whenever the spec uses the word *shall*, any PDF not obeying the spec is considered invalid. (In case the spec is only recommending something, the word *should* is used.)

Summarized: you're asking something that isn't allowed (for now: not recommended; in the future: forbidden).

**Extra remark:** a digital signature in a PDF covers the whole document. There is no use to put a visual mark on each page because that would encourage the misconception that digital signatures in PDF can be used to sign separate pages. The reason to add the *one signature = one widget annotation* in the ISO specification is also educational: whoever demands a widget annotation on every page for a single signature, proves that he or she doesn't understand the concept of digital signatures in PDF ;-)

Comment: This makes sense, additionally there are also the `Action` and `Fields` dictionary property of the Signature Annotation/Widget which locks certain other fields when signed. Thus this is more of an indication of what is signed than a per-page visual signature/initials paradigm to me.